# get perfomance date from cloudstack api

Tags: python, api, apache-cloudstack

Please help me in getting date about perfomace hipervizor using simple api (in my case i used python).

There is simple example who gets list of machines :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import CloudStack

api = 'http://example.com:8080/client/api'
apikey = 'API KEY'
secret = 'API SECRET'

cloudstack = CloudStack.Client(api, apikey, secret)

vms = cloudstack.listVirtualMachines()

for vm in vms:
    print "%s %s %s" % (vm['id'], vm['name'], vm['state'])
```

How from this script i can change it, to get for example CPU of all hipervizor machine?
(if can give info not only about cpu, but about HDD utilization, memory, etc...)

Thanks, very much.

Answer (score 0):

You would get all the VM details along with all the CPU, Memory etc related data for a particular host. pass on the host id for getting the details for all VMs under that host.

I use response=json as param in the URL for getting back all these details in json format for easy parsing. Look at below URL for actual input and output params.

https://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/api/apidocs-4.5/root_admin/listVirtualMachines.html

hope it helps!!